# Cannot create a Domain Certificate in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I am trying to create a Domain certificate on one of my servers. But I cannot select the CA when I run the Wizard. 
The select is greyed out. 
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can enroll certificates from IIS only from default V1 WebServer template. This template must be added to your issuing CA server.

Reference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserversecurity/thread/e3e43894-30d5-4064-93d1-96d46ef3de14

Answer (score 0):

The Select button will be enabled only if a certification authority is correctly configured and exists on the domain.

[Click here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731014(v=ws.10).aspx) for more details.